# Dbeaver SSH Tunnel Error

Tags: ssh, mysql

I can't get the SSH tunnel functionality of Dbeaver to work. SSH works fine via command line, but using Dbeaver I always get the following error:

[image]

I'm using the private key path to my `id_rsa`, its chmod'ed to 600. Like I say, it works perfectly fine from terminal. I'm using latest version of Dbeaver fron software center, and Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: Something like `ssh -L 9000:localhost:5432 user@example.com` works? DBeaver probably is running on a different user than `$USER` (chris). 600 is fine for your private keys.

Comment: Thanks Pablo. Im not sure what you are saying with that command. Do you have any ideas on how to troubleshoot this in dbeaver? I can SSH using the plain ssh  user@host

Comment: Installing the deb file should resolve your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the answer by EugeneSmoliy on github.

> Run this on your key to convert it to RSA private key. Helped me.
>   `ssh-keygen -p -m PEM -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Taken directly from here: https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/5845#issuecomment-503481448

Comment: Ok, thanks for sharing. I had not seen that you were also the OP. ;-)