# DBeaver tunnel connection says ssh-keygen permission denied

Tags: networking, 20.04, ssh, mysql, tunnel

I tried connecting to my remote DB on DBeaver through a tunnel configuration.
I added the required details and tried connecting with my ssh private key, but it is throwing an error saying permission denied to run ssh-keygen.

[image]

Does anybody know the fix for this?

P.S: the tunnel connection to DB works fine when connecting through my terminal using commands.

Comment: may this topic help your problem ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56979849/dbeaver-ssh-tunnel-invalid-private-key or this topic https://askubuntu.com/questions/1203028/dbeaver-ssh-tunnel-error

Comment: @CrazyTux I already tried that. Didnt work

Answer (score 1):

You can switch from Jshc to SSHJ in the SSH connection advanced settings.
Like on this screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

DBbeaver requires your key in RSA format not OPENSSH.
Convert your key using this command:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -m PEM
```